Why can't you use black/orange poly evaporative tubing indoors for a swamp/evaporative cooler?
Seems OK to run "DIAL 1/4 in. x 50 ft. Evaporative Cooler Poly Tube" from a hose spigot to a swamp cooler, why would it say it is for outdoor use only, and thus I can't use it for internal water supply to a rooftop cooler?  The "Copper Tube" equivalent it says is OK for indoor use.


Oh, you can use it...but it is more susceptible to failure and as such it doesn't meet code.  When a connection splits and floods your kitchen, you will then be asking why did I use it.

If it's PEX it should be ok... but it just says poly. so maybe not PEX.  maybe look for icemaker tube instead. it's the same size.

Yeah it says it's "polyethylene" but not for use in "indoors or in attics" https://shop.rplumber.com/c/heating-cooling-ventilation/air-conditioners-coolers/evaporative-cooler-parts-accessories/p/dial-4296-cooler-tubing-polyethylene-black-for-evaporative-cooler-purge-systems-black and it does seem cheaper/wimpier than PEX...Possibly not as fire retardant? Less potable? Their customer service said they hadn't "tested" it indoors [though the copper version is OK?] Definitely wimpier and cheaper than PEX or "icemaker tube" (though the black one better if exposed to sun?)

Dial has a FAQ with this on it:

Why does the label on the Poly Tubing say 'Not for potable water' and
'For outdoor use only'?
Do not use Dial's poly tubing for potable water. The tubing material
has not been approved for potable use. Do not use Dial's poly tubing
for indoor, garage or attic applications. Poly tubing may leak due to
wall thickness variations and tubing degradation over time. Only use
copper tubing that has been approved for indoor applications and/or
potable water.


Sweet, never saw that :)

If you use the poly tubing outdoors where it is exposed to sun, run it through a length of old water hose and it will last longer. Definitely go with the ice maker tubing indoors if not copper.

Good trick.  Dial says their black and "copper color" (red) poly tubing is "Resistant to UV Degradation" but this might be useful if it's in direct sunlight, especially if doesn't have water in it and is getting hit by sun... :)
